# Given $y(t)=y_0+\int_{t_0}^tK(t,t')f(t')dt'$, does $y(t)$ satisfy a linear, first order, ordinary differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given an integral equation of the form $$y(t)=y_0+\int_{t_0}^t K(t,t')f(t')\,\mathrm{d}t',$$ is it true that $y(t)$ satisfies a linear, first order, ordinary  differential equation with the initial condition $y(t_0)=y_0$? What is the equation and how do we get it? Here, both $y(t)$ and $t$ are real variables.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't asking if a function satisfies *some* first-order linear ordinary differential equation equivalent to asking if it's differentiable?

Comment: The answer is basically no, not a useful one anyway. Think about it: the derivative will be $K(t,t) f(t) + \int_{t_0}^t \left ( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} K(t,t') \right ) f(t') dt'$ from the Leibniz rule, where $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}$ means you differentiate with respect to the first argument. There is no avoiding that integral term, and in principle there is no way to relate it back to $y$ itself either. You need the kernel to appear in some convenient form, such as $K(t-t')$.

Comment: @Ian If $K(t,t')=K(t-t')$, do we get a differential equation?

Comment: If you just have that, then you again have a problem. If you have that *and* $K$ itself satisfies a simple differential equation then you have a hope of reaching a nice differential equation. For example $K(t,t')=e^{t-t'}$ then $y(t)=y_0 + \int_{t_0}^t e^{t-t'} y(t') dt'$ and now $y'=y + \int_{t_0}^t e^{t-t'} y(t') dt'=y + y - y_0$. The key reason this worked was that $\frac{\partial K}{\partial t}=K$ so that contribution to the derivative just gave you $y-y_0$, while the other contribution gives you $K(t,t) y$ which was just $y$.